# I am writing a quick sort that is supposed to keep track of the number of iterations. However, the count returns 0 every time. How can I fix this?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Function called from main:

```
int Quicksort::Sort(Data* ary, int left, int right, int count)
{
    count = SortPrivate(ary, left, right, count);
    return count;
}
```

The function that does the actual sorting:

```
int Quicksort::SortPrivate(Data* ary, int left, int right, int count)
{

    if (left < right)
    {
        count++;
        int pivot = Partition(ary, left, right);

        SortPrivate(ary, left, pivot - 1, count);
        SortPrivate(ary, pivot + 1, right, count);

    }
    return count;
}
```

And then this:

```
int Quicksort::Partition(Data* ary, int left, int right)
{
    int pivotValue = ary[left].Get_key();
    int sortLeft = left + 1;
    int sortRight = right;
    bool finished = false;

    while (!finished)
    {
        while (sortLeft <= sortRight && ary[sortLeft].Get_key() <= pivotValue)
            sortLeft++;

        while (ary[sortRight].Get_key() >= pivotValue && sortRight >= sortLeft)
            sortRight--;

        if (sortRight < sortLeft)
            finished = true;
        else
            Exchange(ary, sortLeft, sortRight);
    }

    Exchange(ary, left, sortRight);

    return sortRight;
}
```

I've done some debugging, using the step into process in Visual Studio, and it turns out each time the recursive function returns, it will decrement until the count returns to 0. How do I prevent this from happening? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *pass* as well as *return* `count`?

Comment: Yeah, I had to pass it because it would otherwise reset every time the function is called recursively and I had to return it to get the value back. But as my answer states, to fix that, I changed the functions' return type to void and passed it in by reference instead. It works perfectly now.

Comment: That was the pointer I was trying to give you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I didn't realize it would merely decrement at the end of each recursion all the way back down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I passed count by reference and changed the functions' return type to void, and it works perfectly now. I have to pass in count and have it "returned" somehow since it is called recursively. So to accomplish that, instead of the functions returning anything, I just passed count by reference.